# Event emitter setMaxListeners(15) how does it work here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling, eventemitter

I have two different events on a emitter where I need to set the maxlistener count dynamically. I have surfed many tutorials and docs but could not understand whether the count will be set to each individual event on the emitter or to all the events together it will be set to the particular count.

```
 emitter.on('event1', function(){}) 
 emitter.on('event2', function(){}) 
 emitter.setMaxListeners(15);
```

When we use the above code will the max listener count set for both event1 and event2 combined to 15 or will it set listener count to each individual event to 15.

Eg:

```
Case 1:

event1 -- Max 15 listeners

event2 -- Max 15 listeners
```

OR

```
Case 2:

event1 listener + event2 listener  -- Max 15 listeners?
```

Is it case 1 or case 2 that it sets?

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated..

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By default EventEmitters will print a warning if more than 10
>   listeners are added for a particular event.

It means that the limit is per event for an eventemitter.

> The emitter.setMaxListeners() method allows the limit to be modified
>   for this specific EventEmitter instance. The value can be set to
>   Infinity (or 0) to indicate an unlimited number of listeners.

Reference [here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n)

The Eventemitter `setMaxListener` sheds more light.

> By default, a maximum of 10 listeners can be registered for any single
>   event. This limit can be changed for individual EventEmitter instances
>   using the emitter.setMaxListeners(n) method.

Reference [here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_eventemitter_defaultmaxlisteners).

Although it is not explicitly stated in the docs, it can be implied from the above two links

Comment: Means overall will the listeners count be 30?
Because its nowhere mentioned in the doc whether the count is being set for single event.

Comment: The warning limit is per event, so when calling `setMaxlisteners` it will update per event. The limit is per event